# Using RewriteRule shows apache folder navigation or 404, why?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress installed and in the root i created a folder and put an .htaccess inside to redirect to another web page without changing the URL.

This was working fine until i move to another server (the older one was just horrible) and now it just not working.

This is code that i was using:

```
RewriteEngine ON    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/conexionalam
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1 [R=301,L,P]
```

and is no longer working, show me this:

[image]

looking for internet i have tested some other codes:

1-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/conexionalam(/.*|)$ nuevoserver.breinguash.com$1 [L,NC]
```

2-

```
RewriteEngine ON  
RewriteRule   ^/(.+)  http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1  [R,L]
```

This two show me this:

[image]

3-

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1
```

This one redirect me to http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/index.html

I realized that if i took off this '[R=301,L,P]' at the end of the first code, it works but changing the URL and i don't want tat.

Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT:**

By the moment im using this code:

```
RewriteEngine ON    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/conexionalam
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1
```

Its redirects but change the URL = /
but for now does not affect google analytics.

if i change or add something to the code it does show me the errors from above. i really doesn't understand why it does that.

---

**SOLUTION**

Well it seem  that i cant redirect between domains/subdomains without changing the URL just like that, i have to do it with proxy, so the solution was:

- Enable proxy and proxy-http on apache.
- Use the P flag for RewriteRule

So right now i'm using this code and it works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine ON    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/conexionalam
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1 [R=301,L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot in your .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^conexionalam(.*)$ http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should redirect you to http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com when you go to /conexionalam from your main domain.

Comment: /conexionalam/ is a folder inside my main domain inside wordpress: http://i.imgur.com/cO78zNe.png

Comment: I follow what you are trying to do now, using the rewrite engine you will always get something similar to this as it will make the sub domain you are trying to connect to appear as though it is in the local directory, in other words transparent redirect. If you want it to simply bounce the user to the sub domain the easiest and most easily managed method would be to create the conexionalam directory, in it create an index.php file, and in the file type `<?php header("location: http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com") ?>`. This will automatically redirect as desired and no htaccess needed.

Comment: This redirect but changes the URL and i don't want that. Besides, what about the urls like 'conexionalam/something'.

Comment: Also, sorry if i didn't clarify that http://nuevoserver.breinguash.com is another wordpress.